# Extract the contents of a plain/text in rest assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am getting a response from my RestAssured call as ContentType `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`.
I searched the internet but am unable to find a nice way to get the content out of the message as using the below is not so nice;

```
String content = response.then().extract().body().htmlPath().get().children().get(0).toString();
```

How can I extract the contents of this response a little more nice?

Comment: Whats the actual response content? If the content type is `text/plain` why are you using `htmlPath`? Are you getting html content but with content type of `text/plain`?

Comment: It is a plaintext containing for example `ABCDE` so no html it is indeed a `text/plain`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can directly use .asString() to get the body content of the response irrespective of this return Content-Type.

You can try something like that:

```
response.then().extract().body().asString();
```

or directly:

```
response.asString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

String ResponseAsString=given().get("http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/IND/UP").asString();
            System.out.println("My ResponseAsString is:"+ResponseAsString);

Also you can extract the response using JsonPath even though it's ContentType.TEXT

```
Response response=given().contentType(ContentType.TEXT).get("http://localhost:3000/posts");
      //we need to convert response as a String and give array index
    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(response.asString());
    String title = jsonPath.getString("title[2]");
    String author=jsonPath.getString("author[2]");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way it work to me

```
import io.restassured.response.Response;

response.getBody().prettyPrint();
```